# Is this an Android developers' forum, or just end users?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm just getting starting on Android development.  I'm using IntelliJ.

Is this a good forum for development questions, or is it more geared towards system and end users?

Trying to decide whether to put my Android questions here or on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You've seen an invitation to take the [tour], haven't you?

Comment: @zaq  Actually I hadn't, but I did assume there was one and that with this question someone would post it for me pretty promto.  Cheers.  I'll read it.

Comment: @zaq Quote: "Don't ask about... Android Development..."  Seems to answer my question pretty succinctly.

Comment: Thanks for checking before posting a lot of off-topic questions. Not everyone is so thoughtful.